# Selectively bypass data type converter

Tags: python, sqlite

I have a SQL database I query using sqlite3 in Python and I have created a custom data type called FOOBAR. Columns with this data type store a string which is a file path. When queried, the converter opens the file and returns some data, which works perfectly.

I was wondering if there is any way I can pull just the file path string out of the column, i.e. selectively NOT apply the converter for this custom data type from time to time.

Comment: Have you tried just querying the database without the converter?

Comment: @bernie How can I do that? If I do "SELECT col1 FROM table1" where col1 is FOOBAR type, it always apply the converter. How can I tell it not to?

Comment: @bernie I'm sorry but I don't understand. Try what? Of course SQLite has data types and I do need to use them. And I'd like the converter applied to most query results but want to know if there is a way to selectively apply it. HOW can I query the database without the converter? Can you be more specific please? Is this a silly question? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It's not at all a silly question. I was under the impression that you could easily selectively apply a converter. Apparently that is not the case.

Comment: @bernie: you can, if you use the `PARSE_COLNAMES` mode (where the converter type is taken from the column name, where you augment each column in a query with a special `as "colname [typename]"` alias). You then have to you specify *per query* if a converter is to be used. That can be cumbersome if you have a lot of queries and the vast majority use conversions.

Comment: @MartijnPieters thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using the [`PARSE_DECLTYPES` method](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.PARSE_DECLTYPES) of hooking in your conversion, use a [`CAST`](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html#castexpr) to 'change' the type of your column:

```sql
select CAST(filename as TEXT) from table where <filter>
```

That causes SQLite to report the filename to have a different type (text in this case) bypassing the type conversion associated with the column.

Demo, adapted from the [`Point()` example from the documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html#converting-sqlite-values-to-custom-python-types):

```
>>> import sqlite3
>>> class Point(object):
...     def __init__(self, x, y):
...         self.x, self.y = x, y
...     def __repr__(self):
...         return "Point(%f, %f)" % (self.x, self.y)
...
>>> def adapt_point(point):
...     return "%f;%f" % (point.x, point.y)
...
>>> def convert_point(s):
...     return Point(*(float(c) for c in s.split(";")))
...
>>> sqlite3.register_adapter(Point, adapt_point)
>>> sqlite3.register_converter("point", convert_point)
>>> p = Point(4.0, -3.2)
>>> con = sqlite3.connect(":memory:", detect_types=sqlite3.PARSE_DECLTYPES)
>>> cur = con.cursor()
>>> cur.execute("create table test(p point)")
<sqlite3.Cursor object at 0x105d03650>
>>> cur.execute("insert into test(p) values (?)", (p,))
<sqlite3.Cursor object at 0x105d03650>
>>> cur.execute("select p from test").fetchone()[0]
Point(4.000000, -3.200000)
>>> cur.execute("select cast(p as text) from test").fetchone()[0]
u'4.000000;-3.200000'
```

If you are using the [`PARSE_COLNAMES` method](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.PARSE_COLNAMES), simply don't include a type in the column name alias when querying.